# set zoom after each redraw

Tags: d3.js, dagre-d3

I am using 'dagre d3' for displaying dependency graph. I also use slider(which I use to display step by step evolution of graph when user slides the slider) so each time Slider is moved, graph is redrawn. For the first time, 'zoom' feature will be set like below:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
inner.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" +
    "scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
});
svg.call(zoom);
```

I want to retain the zoom level if the user has zoomed in or zoomed out the graph and then moved the slider. So make it work, I did the following. 
this method will be called whenever user slides the slider.

```
function redrawGraphToStage(stageToRedraw) {
    // Not sure how to get previous values. below one works but feel its bit hacky. 
    if(inner[0][0].transform.animVal.length){
        tempInnerTranslate = [inner[0][0].transform.animVal[0].matrix.e, inner[0][0].transform.animVal[0].matrix.f];
        tempInnerScale = inner[0][0].transform.animVal[1].matrix.a;
}
// do modifications to graph. and re-render. 
if(tempInnerScale || tempInnerTranslate){
    //  this will set up the zoom level to before.
    zoom.translate(tempInnerTranslate).scaleExtent(tempInnerScale, tempInnerScale).event(svg);        
}
```

Even though it setup the zoom level to previous values, I wont be able to zoom after this. Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try with,

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", zoomed);
svg.call(zoom);

function zoomed() {
    inner.attr("transform",
        "translate(" + zoom.translate() + ")" +
        "scale(" + zoom.scale() + ")"
    );
}

function redrawGraphToStage(stageToRedraw) {
    // Not sure how to get previous values. below one works but feel its bit hacky. 
    if(inner[0][0].transform.animVal.length){
        tempInnerTranslate = [inner[0][0].transform.animVal[0].matrix.e, inner[0][0].transform.animVal[0].matrix.f];
        tempInnerScale = inner[0][0].transform.animVal[1].matrix.a;
}
// do modifications to graph. and re-render. 
if(tempInnerScale || tempInnerTranslate){
    //  this will set up the zoom level to before.
    zoom.translate(tempInnerTranslate).scale(tempInnerScale, tempInnerScale);
    zoomed();        
}
```

I'm not sure what you're using the slider for, but I made you a demo where you can control the zoom scale with a slider bar. **Significant change:** `scaleIntent` replaced with `scale`.

[JSFiddle working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davcs86/m2pofp2t/3/)

Comment: Thanks for your time. I tried this but still same issue. I am not able to zoom again after redraw.

Comment: I've included a demo in jsfiddle, I think it can help you.